# Python module resolution for Google App Engine vs Google Cloud NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm

I'm trying to create a Python 3 application for Google App Engine (using `PyCharm`).

I think I'm running into a basic problem in which a module named "google" is defined in 2 places: in the Google App Engine directory created by `gcloud install`, and in my project's venv directory when I pip install add-ons such as `google-cloud-ndb` via the `requirements.txt` file.

When I select `PyCharm` Settings | Frameworks | App Engine and specify the directory into which `gcloud` installed `App Engine`, the editor can resolve things like `import google.appengine` but not `import google.cloud`. If I unselect the `App Engine` Framework, then the editor can find `import google.cloud`, but not `import google.appengine`.

All the code examples just list `import google.xyz`, so I imagine when I deploy, `Google` will resolve all this correctly.  But it also means I probably shouldn't play around with naming or imports either.

This is so basic. How is this handled?

Comment: Can you confirm that you followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72825830/18265570) while doing `pip install`. and what is the `python` version you are using? Have you tried installing[`google-api-python-client`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72825830/18265570)?

Comment: I am using Python3.9.  The venv is working correctly, and resolves other non-conflicting packages such as Flask.  The problem is that PyCharm can only resolve a package in one place, and now 'google' exists in 2 places (local App Engine installation and venv), with different modules.  I don't understand why everyone doesn't have this problem? If I manually copy the files into one location the editor can resolve it, but this seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a Flask project, not an App Engine project, and then copy installed App Engine modules into the project's venv, so PyCharm can see all google sub-modules in one place.

There's more to getting PyCharm to truly develop/run/debug Python 3 App Engine apps, though: see [How to test/run/debug Non-Legacy App Engine project using PyCharm on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852788/how-to-test-run-debug-non-legacy-app-engine-project-using-pycharm-on-windows/76942026#76942026)

Answer (score 0):

How did you install your App Engine SDK? Why would your `google.cloud` and `google.appengine` locations be different? Your mileage may vary, esp. if your install has been around your machine for a long time (well-curated.

On my Mac, both libraries seem to install properly in the same folder, and I'm able to import them without issue (see below). Nothing fancy here... no PyCharm, no `venv`/`virtualenv`, etc.

```
$ pip3 install -U pip appengine-python-standard google-cloud-ndb
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (23.3.1)
Collecting appengine-python-standard
  Using cached appengine_python_standard-1.1.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
Collecting google-cloud-ndb
  Using cached google_cloud_ndb-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
    . . .
Installing collected packages: appengine-python-standard, google-cloud-ndb
Successfully installed appengine-python-standard-1.1.4 google-cloud-ndb-2.2.2
$
$ ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google
_upb            appengine       gapic           oauth2          type
api             auth            logging         protobuf
api_core        cloud           longrunning     rpc
$
$ python3
Python 3.11.2 (v3.11.2:878ead1ac1, Feb  7 2023, 10:02:41) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google.appengine
>>> import google.cloud
>>>
```

As an aside, you should only be using the App Engine SDK in Python 3 if you're migrating an existing Python 2 app. The sole purpose of the SDK is to [help ease the transition](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/support-for-app-engine-services-in-second-generation-runtimes), but those services under `google.appengine` are older and don't have any new features since Python 2. Also see [this blog post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/10/extending-support-for-app-engine-bundled-services-module-17.html?utm_source=%20blog&utm_medium=partner&utm_campaign=CDR_wes_aap-serverless_mgrwormhole_sms_202002).

If you're developing new (Python 3) App Engine apps, you shouldn't be using it, meaning none of the `google.appengine` libraries. Instead, you should be using the newer GCP replacements (most have one). These live under `google.cloud`. To learn how to migrate from Python 2 App Engine services or just start using the new GCP libraries in Python 3, see all of the content at the [migration repo](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/migrate-python2-appengine). Learn about the migration content from [this post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/03/modernizing-your-google-app-engine-applications.html?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=partner&utm_campaign=CDR_wes_aap-serverless_modernizegae_codelabsannounce_201031) (re the codelabs) and [this one](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/introducing-serverless-migration.html?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=partner&utm_campaign=CDR_wes_aap-serverless_smsintro_201023) (re the videos).

Comment: I am developing on Windows via PyCharm on a new PC, migrating from Python 2.  As mentioned, I installed the SDK via `gcloud install`. SDK is needed for code completion and potentially for local testing.  I am using venv for the modules added via requirements.txt.  At this point, one of the leading Python IDEs (PyCharm) has dropped support for App Engine development on Windows, and says it cannot be done.  My solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852788/how-to-test-run-debug-non-legacy-app-engine-project-using-pycharm-on-windows/76942026#76942026

Comment: Wow, that's "complicated." Glad you got it working. I tried my best to smoothen the transition from Python 2 to 3 on App Engine but couldn't get to all the corners. I suggest you write a full blog post on setting it up with full details & commentary then link to it from SO.

I'm working on a series on API keys for http://dev.to/wescpy but after that, I plan on a blog post specifically for Python 2 App Engine users on their various options moving forward.